# Update all properties in list using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to update all the properties in a list object using linq.

For ex.: I have an User List with (Name, Email, PhoneNo,...) as properties. 
I will get the Users List(`List<Users>`) from database which is filled with all properties except Email. I need to update all the Email property in the list after retrieving from database with some email in session.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do it simply via `ForEach`..

```
users.ForEach(user => user.email = sessionEmail);
```

or for multiple properties..

```
users.ForEach(user => 
{
    user.email = sessionEmail;
    user.name = "Some Person";
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thats perfect. Thanks Quintin

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to retrieve all the users who have no email assigned. Then, what about something like this:

```
var users=dataContext.Users.Where(user => user.email==null).ToList();
foreach(var user in users) {
  user.Email="some@email.com"; //Or, choose a different email for each user
}
```

And if you want to update the users information back to the database:

```
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```